# Android c2dm service

Tags: java, android

Trying to implement google C2DM service.

```
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender","example@gmail.com");
context.startService(registrationIntent);
```

Almost every tutorial features this line of code. Is this a service that I must code? or does Android know how to handle this type of Intent. I am calling this method from a helper class with the default constructor. I pass the current Context to the this above method to create the registration Intent. Anyone have some insight on how this works or where my program will go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to write a service. You need to send an intent to a Google's service. You've omitted the first line, where the intent is created, and that contains the service name. It's something like this typically:

Intent registrationIntent　= new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");

The line `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER` identifies the Google's service.

Now, you still have to write the broadcast receiver that'll receive the registration result (either an ID or error). And a receiver to receive the actual C2DM messages.

Comment: I know I omitted the first line. Was hoping to find someone familar with c2dm...like yourself it seems. Is Google's service in the Android 2.2 API? or do I need to pull it from somewhere else?

Comment: It's present in Android 2.2 and higher, save for maybe some extreme customizations.

Comment: Addition: on devices like Kindle Fire and Nook Tablet it probably won't be present. Those vendors (Amazon and B&N) are trying hard to get rid of all entanglement with Google's cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the most interesting piece of code

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
```

> Is this a service that I must code? or does Android know how to handle this type of Intent.

Note that the intent is in the *com.google.android.c2dm* domain. The Android C2DM implementation on the device knows how to handle this intent and you will be starting its own service to process it.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I know about the first line, didn't think it would be important since i'm targeting members familiar with c2dm. Is the c2dm implementation always on the device if it is V2.2 and above? or do I need to pull the c2dm directory from somewhere?

Comment: @Ryan Gray: The _C2DM_ service is bundled with the _Android Market_ since some (don't remember which) version, you dont need (and can't) pull it from elsewhere.